# Windows Phone 8.1 Value Converter parameter from codebehind with datacontext already given

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm facing an issue while developing an app for windows Phone 8.1.

Here's the case:

I have looked up my current position, and stored that as a variable of type GeoPosition in my codebehind.

Now I have a listview, with places. Each place also has a longitude and latitude, stored in a geoObject class.
My listview has a certain datacontext, a ObservableCollection.
I'm trying to use a valueConverter, to calculate the distance between my current location and the location for each item.
I have set my current location to be the ConverterParameter, but my guess is that it's always empty, because the system looks for the value in the datacontext of my listview.
The datacontext for the parameter should be the codebehind.

I have written in pseude code what I would like to do

> Text="{Binding geodata , 
>                                                                                                                      Converter={StaticResource DistanceConverter},
>                                                                                                                      ConverterParameter={Binding currentPosition,
>   RelativeSource=myCodeBehind}}"

is there any way to set the codebehind as the datacontext ONLY for the converter parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you move both the current position and the `ObservableCollection` of places to some Viewmodel, and set the whole window's `DataContext` to an instance of this Viewmodel. Then, specify the `ObservableCollection` as the `ListView`'s **ItemsSource** (instead of setting its `DataContext`).

Now, both the list of places and the current position should be accessible to the window and thus also to all ValueConverters referenced within the window, since both are defined within the window's Viewmodel. The binding could look similar to the following (might not match exactly since I don't know the exact structure of you window):

```
Text="{Binding geodata , Converter={StaticResource DistanceConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.currentPosition}"
```